# Reading USB with ioctl fails for "value too large for defined data type"

Tags: android, serial-port, usb, ioctl, ftdi

I am trying to read USB using with an ioctl and USBDEVFS_BULK (in native on Android). The USB cable I am using contains an FTDI chip and sends data over from an Arduino UNO, which writes Serial.

The write on Android seems to always succeed but the read either always fail, or succeeds for a few entries then constantly fail with "Value too large for defined data type" (75). I am using this setup a simple ping test: write one byte, a sequence number on Android; Arduino reads the byte and replies with the same sequence number.

I am not completely sure what this error is saying. The way I understood it is that the device sent more data than the buffer I pass to the ioctl can accommodate. I've made sure that my Arduino sends only 1 byte back, and I expect to see 2 more for the FTDI, for a total of 3 bytes. Even increasing the buffer size does not seem to fix the issue.

```
char mReadData[3];
struct usbdevfs_bulktransfer bulkTransferRead = {
    mReadEndpoint,  // Endpoint
    3,              // Length in bytes
    0,              // Timeout (ms)
    mReadData,     // Data
};

ret = ioctl(mFd, USBDEVFS_BULK, &bulkTransferRead);
```

This is the code I am using natively. If I try to use Android/Java code for the read and write (using bulkTransfer()) I am seeing the same intermittent issue with the read. In Java on Android, I've made sure to do the following before any write/read:

1) Reset pin
  2) Set baud rate
  3) 8N1

Can anyone please help me describe what I am misunderstanding about FTDI/USB or explain this errno about "value too large for defined data type" please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. It seems this error, EOVERFLOW, can be fixed just by specifying a buffer size that is equal to the max packet size of the endpoint. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error recently as well, thanks @Jary for pointing me in the right direction.  For anyone else who ends up here looking for what that max packet size might be, plug your device into a Linux box and find the desired device and endpoint:

`lsusb -v | grep 'Bus\|bEndpointAddress\|wMaxPacketSize\|idVendor\|idProduct'`

Example output:

```
Bus 001 Device 027: ID 0451:d109 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
  idVendor           0x0451 Texas Instruments, Inc.
  idProduct          0xd109 
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        wMaxPacketSize     0x001c  1x 28 bytes
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
```

The max packet size you need for the buffer is given under the endpoint address.

For further information see [this page](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb4.shtml) which states among other interesting tidbits:

> Bulk transfers are only supported by full and high speed devices. *For
>   full speed endpoints, the maximum bulk packet size is either 8, 16, 32
>   or 64 bytes long. For high speed endpoints, the maximum packet size
>   can be up to 512 bytes long.* If the data payload falls short of the
>   maximum packet size, it doesn't need to be padded with zeros. A bulk
>   transfer is considered complete when it has transferred the exact
>   amount of data requested, transferred a packet less than the maximum
>   endpoint size, or transferred a zero-length packet. *(Emphasis mine)*

Buffers need to be equal to one of these sizes.  Making them arbitrarily large or just some other value (eg. 1024 bytes) doesn't seem to work.  In my case the buffer was originally 64 bytes which worked with older devices but it failed with the OP's error when connected to a newer device which had a 512 byte max packet size.  Increasing to 512 bytes worked for me and older devices still seem to work fine.